# How spacing is calculated in HStack

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, hstack

In SwiftUI when a horizontal array of `Circle`s are made like this:

```
HStack(spacing : 4) {
  Foreach(0..<5) { index in
    Circle()
  }
}
```

How the (horizontal) spacing value of `4` is applied? Is it between the centre of two circles or from their edges instead?

Comment: The `spacing` is *between* view frames (nothing about internals, like center, etc.)

Comment: Did you run this code? It's quite clear when you see it in action.

Comment: Yes. I tried it with just two circles . In the editor canvs guidelines appeared at the outer points. But I got different results when I used this for calculation. (Total length = length of line + half the radii of two circles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on top of @Asperi's comment: the spacing is applied in the same way it's applied to `Text` or `Button` standard views, which is between the *frames* of the views.

If you click on an element in the preview (this doesn't work when on live preview mode), you can see the frame of an element outlined in blue. The spacing is applied between the edges of the frames of each view.